# Jquery mobile doesnt prevent scroll in windows mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

As in JQM even a single click is Ajax call...in my application when user click on any link a process indicator appears on screen... When process indicator appears then user should not scroll the screen and background area should not be clickable i.e it should prevent from click.

I have written code:

```js
disabelScroll()
{
    $(document).on(scroll,function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 e.stoppropogation();
    });
    $(document).on(scrollstart,function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 e.stoppropogation();
    });
}
```

I have called this function when my processing indicator starts...i.e. when ajax request is send

It does work on all mobile platform like android,iphone,ipad,blackberry but in windows mobile it's not working.
In windows mobile it does call `disableScroll()` but is doesn't stop its behaviour...i.e. when Spinner is displayed user is able to scroll and can click which should not happen.

Can anyone please help me in this issue?

Comment: it's `e.stopPropogation();` and why not just use `retrun false;`?

Comment: yup...its e.stopPropogation(); 
also i have used e.stopimmediatePropagation();
how does return false will work..?...can u please explain??
i am not getting why is doesn't work in windows mobile only...it works is all other mobile...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

and

```
e.stopPropogation();
```

solves my issue